# How do I find the floating point value ending in most zero decimal digits in a given range?

Tags: algorithm, math, floating-point

Does anyone have an algorithm to find the floating point value between "min" and "max" that ends in the most zero digits when printed in decimal (or has the fewest decimal places, to put it another way). Of course there may be several solutions: in the range from 500 to 2500, either 1000 or 2000 are as good. For my purposes, either will do.
   It's to reimplement the axis-labelling code in sndfile-spectrogram so my target language is C, but math/pseudocode is fine.

Comment: almost imposible with radix 2 floating point

Comment: Are you looking for an exactly representable floating-point number, or is this really a question about mathematical real numbers? For example, what answers would you consider valid for the range `(0.121, 0.131)`?

Comment: Yes, it's a math question, not a floating point representation question. It doesn't have to be exactly representable as it's to find an anchor point to run a graph's scale ticks from, so (0.121, 0.131) should give 0.130 (or a close representable value to that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think this will get the highest such number.

```
float max = 432.334, min = 431.214; // The numbers you are looking between
float r = 0.01; // The first decimal place to check
float x0 = max, x1 = max; // Working variables
while (x1 > min)
{
    x0 = x1;
    x1 = r*floor(x1/r)
    r *= 10;
}
```

Your answer is x0.

---

**Edit:** A bit more explanation

This works by rounding the larger number down to successively increasing powers of 10. The `r*floor(x1/r)` does this rounding down. As a worked example:

```
r = 0.001
min, max = 0.1212, 0.1315
x1 = max

# Store the old value
x0 = x1
   = 0.1315

# Round down to the nearest r
x1 = r*floor(x1/r)
   = 0.001*floor(0.1315/0.001)
   = 0.001*floor(131.5)
   = 0.001*131
   = 0.131

# x1 is still larger than min, so multiply r by 10 and repeat
r  = 10*r
   = 10*0.001
   = 0.01
x0 = x1
   = 0.131
x1 = r*floor(x1/r)
   = 0.01*floor(0.131/0.01)
   = 0.01*floor(13.1)
   = 0.01*13
   = 0.13

# and again...
r  = 10*r
   = 10*0.01
   = 0.1
x0 = x1
   = 0.13
x1 = r*floor(x1/r)
   = 0.1*floor(0.13/0.1)
   = 0.1*floor(1.3)
   = 0.1*1
   = 0.1

# x1 is now smaller than min, so the loop ends. x0 is the last rounded value
# larger than min, so this is the answer.
```