# Finding number with max zeros(binary rep) from a given range

Tags: algorithm, binary

Given a range (low, high) of numbers, how to find the number (within that range) that has the most zeros in its binary representation ? For example, given a range 5 to 15, answer is 8

Comment: What would the answer be for the range 5-7 inclusive? Both 5 and 6 would have 1 zero while 7 doesn't have any zeros.

Comment: if there are multiple answers with same max value, any of the numbers could be the answer.

Comment: [See this related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541146/how-do-i-find-the-floating-point-value-ending-in-most-zero-decimal-digits-in-a-g).  It doesn't have a marked solution yet, and I think the posted answer might have some issues with floating point errors.  However, the general idea is correct and you won't have any floating point errors in binary or with integer arithmetic.

Comment: Have you tried successively removing the least significant bit of `high` while it's greater than or equal `low`? Can't prove this is correct, but I'd start there.

Comment: Since, the sum of all previous digits cannot equal the current digit it is the case that repeatedly removing the least significant digit from high will always lower the value of high, and lower it by the least amount that flipping a one to a zero could lower it by (given LSD). There can be no pareto-optimal solutions here. Which bits can I flip to give the higher number more zeros without lowering it beyond this threshold, will always select the least significant digit. So yeah, losing bits off the little end should always result in a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `0 < Min < Max`

```
mask = 1 << intlog2(Min ^ Max)
answer = (Min + (mask-1)) & (-mask)
```

intlog2(x) is the position of the highest bit set in binary rep of number x

Example:

```
Min = 5, Max = 15
mask = 1 << intlog2(5 ^ 15) = 1 << intlog2(10) = 1 << 3 = 8
answer = (5 + (8-1)) & (-8) = 12 & (-8) = 8
```